# Theory of Fields $\omega$-Inconsistent?

Tags: logic, finite-fields, model-theory

A theory is [$\omega$-inconsistent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A9-consistent_theory) if there is a predicate $P(n)$ that is true for every standard natural number yet not true for all numbers. Consider the theory of [finite fields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field) and let $P(x) = (Sx \neq 0)$. In any pseudo-finite field, $P(x)$ is true for every standard natural number yet false for $-1$. Is the theory of finite fields $\omega$-inconsistent? What about the theory of [real closed fields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_closed_field)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The expression $\forall n \varphi(n)$, where $n$ ranges over the natural numbers, can be formulated in neither theory. So there is no *notion* of $\omega$-inconsistency for either mentioned theory.

Comment: Don't we need some notion of natural number to talk about $finite$ fields?

Comment: We can be lazy, and let the theory of finite fields be the set of all sentences (over the natural language of field theory) which are true in all finite fields. Natural numbers are not definable in the theory. For real-closed fields, there is a standard axiomatization (infinite, the theory is not finitely axiomatizable.) There is no formula $\psi(x)$ in this theory such that $\psi(x)$ holds iff $x$ is one of $1,1+1,1+1+1,\dots$.

Comment: Which fields are the finite fields? Your answer seems to apply to any theory. We can't define the numbers $1, 1+1, 1+1+1, ...$ in PA either.

Comment: But all quantifiers range over the natural numbers. We can also do it in a theory of the naturals, ince we can use $\exists s\exists t\exists u\exists v(s^2+t^2+u^2+v^2)$ to define the naturals. And we can do it in a theory of the rationals, since Julia Robinson gave a formula $\varphi(n)$, with the dummy variables ranging over the rationals, such that $\varphi(n)$ is true in the rationals iff $n$ is a natural number.  But we cannot do something similar in either of the theories you mention.

Comment: @Russell: The first line in the definition of $\omega$-consistent theory requires that $T$ is able to interpret arithmetic properly. Note that the theory of finite fields does not interpret arithmetic. If it were, then in every finite field we could have interpreted every true formula about the natural numbers. How could you prove that $\forall x(x+1\neq 0)$ in a finite field? (Hint: You can't.)

Comment: There are typos in the second sentence of my comment above. It should say "$\dots$ in a theory of the integers, since $\dots$."